# Dropwizard HttpSession with Redis

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I am looking to be able to use the following Jetty HttpSessionManager -> Redis with Dropwizard:

https://github.com/Ovea/jetty-session-redis

You can tell Dropwizard to use HttpSession with the following:

`environment.servlets().setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());`

However Dropwizard provides no way to give xml config in order to tell Jetty to use the Redis session bundle above.

How can I achieve using Redis with Dropwizard for session management?

Comment: Good question Jake!

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure the SessionDataStore in dropwizard. By default, jetty also provides some useful implementation of session data store (like jdbc, mongo & file). But it's not configurable in Dropwizard yet.